# How to call a javascript variable inside Rails ERB tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, erb

I am getting the Job search results from my Rails action by using Sunspot solr as JSON, and i m creating the result view  in client side by parsing the JSON data & creating HTML elements using Javascript.But from the response JSON we cant get the Job Association objects, So by using company_id field from the response JSON , am trying to access the company from the javascript itself with help of embedded ruby tag.

```
  function submitForm() {
   var valuesToSubmit = $('#FRM_JOB_SEARCH').serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $('#FRM_JOB_SEARCH').attr('action'),
    data :valuesToSubmit,
    success : function(json){
      var data = JSON.parse(json);
          $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                          create_blocks(key , val);
        });
    } ,
    dataype : 'json' ,
    remote : true });

    }

  function create_blocks(key , value) {
       var feeds = eval(value)
          var company_id = feeds["company_id"];
          var company_name = '<%= Company.find_by_id('company_id').name %>';
          console.log(company_name);
   }
```

But this variable is not accessible inside ERB tag.How can we access a javascript variable inside RAILS erb tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aleks said, you can't do that because you are using ruby code in a function that is called in a callback.  The simplest way to achieve what you want to do is to pass the company name in the json data you get from the server.

If you're using `to_json` to render the json response, try the following

```
 render json: @records.to_json(methods: [:company_name])
```

Then in the model, add the `company_name` method

```
 def company_name
   company.name
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, because javascript is on client's side, and erb is on servers slide.

Usually if you want to pass some variable to erb , you can fetch that variable in controller in a specific action, (if you like), and pass that data to the erb.

You can take a look at railcasts [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?autoplay=true) how you can do that.